# Checkout Troubles in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1.3

I am having issues with the **checkout section** in **Magento 2**. I have version 2.1.3 installed in the community version. I bought an extension and the checkout has not been working properly. The developer of the extension has been trying to work on it but also mentioned that even with the default magento chic the same problem is present. I have included the screen shot of the issue and also the url of the site. [image]

No one has been able to help me with this issue.

https://www.freezerworkwear.com/development/

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: This is high-level error, more details should be in exception.log or debug.log(contains response from Braintree if debug mode is enabled) or use xdebug to find original reason in `\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder`

Comment: Is your gateway in test mode as i just tried to place an order using braintree test cards and it is not allowing them please provide steps to reproduct the error

Answer (score 0):

This message unfortunately does not show real error coming from the Braintree payment method. In order to see an error you have to log in to the server and navigate to a [MagentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.3/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php#L84) and update the following code in the savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder method:

**Before**

```
throw new CouldNotSaveException(
    __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
    $e
);
```

**After**

```
throw new CouldNotSaveException(
    __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again. ' . $e->getMessage()),
    $e
);
```

With this change you will be able to see error message when placing order. If this message tells you maybe that Braintree configuration settings should be updated, simple go and update. Otherwise place error message here.

Important: Once you finish, make sure to remove code to the **Before** state to avoid any unfriendly messages shown on checkout page.

If you aren't quote technical, let me know, i will help.